# Converse of Heine-Cantor Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, compactness, uniform-continuity

Heine-Cantor theorem asserts that every continuous function on a compact metric space is uniformly continuous.

The converse is , if every continous function is uniformly continuous on a metric space X then X is compact. I have got the answer that the converse is false but I am unable to find a counter example.

The other question is if the converse is false then its negation must be true.

**Negation**- if every continous function is uniformly continuous on a metric space X **and** X is **not** compact.

How do we prove this?

Comment: I think this can help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316143/inverse-of-heine-cantor-theorem

Comment: You cannot prove it: there *are* non-compact spaces where every continuous function is uniformly continuous. But a valid question it certainly is.

Comment: $\{0\}$ is  a counter-example for your last statment. Your logic is flawed.

Comment: This question has been asked many times. Here is a good answer to the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316143/inverse-of-heine-cantor-theorem?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Then what would be the correct negation.

Comment: If every continuous function on $X$ is uniformly continuous then  $X$  need not be compact. Or you can say: If every continuous function on $X$ is uniformly continuous then  $X$ is not necessarily compact.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I made the negation of ' If A then B ' to 'A and not B'. Btw can I conclude from your negation that compact spaces are not the only spaces on which every continuous function is uniformly continous'.

Answer (score 3):

Theorem 1 of [this old paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1103040241) gives conditions on a metric space so that all continuous functions on it are uniformly continuous.

It seems to me that $\Bbb Z$ (as a subspace of $\Bbb R$) is an easy example of such a non-compact space. And also $\Bbb Z \cup \{\frac1n: n =1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is one that is non-discrete too. As the theorem 1  quoted above shows, we do need lots of "far away" isolated points for this to happen, and in "nice" metric spaces this will imply compactness.

BTW the negation of the converse is: there exists a non-compact $X$ such that every continuous function on $X$ is uniformly continuous.