# Uniformly continuous function and compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness, uniform-continuity

If every continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ (where $X$ is a subset of a compact metric space), is uniformly continuous, then am I right to assume that $X$ is compact as well?

I think it should but I'm not sure if I am correct.  Like if $X$ is a subset of a compact metric space then shouldn't $X$ itself the domain be compact as well if $f$ is uniformly continuous?

Comment: [Spaces with the property: Uniformly continuous equals continuous](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461741/spaces-with-the-property-uniformly-continuous-equals-continuous)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $K$ be a compact metric space such that $X \subseteq K$. Suppose $X$ is not compact, then $X$ is not closed in $K$, hence there is a point $k \in \bar X \setminus X$. Consider the function 
$$ f \colon X \to \mathbb R, \quad x \mapsto \frac 1{d(x,k)} $$
($d$ denoting the metric of $K$). Then $f$ is continuous, but not uniformly continuous, as in the letter case, $f$ would have a continuous extension to $\bar X$, which is impossible.

Comment: So I'm wrong afterall? oh boy

Comment: You aren't wrong. Why do you think so?

Comment: @user97994 He's shown "$X$ not compact $\implies$ there exists a continuous, not uniformly continuous $f$". This is equivalent to what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the following paper:

Is Every Continuous Function Uniformly Continuous? by Ray F. Snipes
Mathematics Magazine, Vol. 57, No. 3 (May, 1984), pp. 169-173
Published by: Mathematical Association of America
Stable URL: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689666 .